# Git checkout workflow

Tags: git

I'm confused with the `git checkout` command to switch branch. I'm in my other branch, I made changes on a file, but I didn't "`git add`". I switched to my `master` branch, and I see the changes on that file.

Why does the changes carried to the master branch when I made the change on the other branch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053757/checkout-another-branch-when-there-are-uncommitted-changes-on-the-current-branch)

Comment: Sounds like the file isn't tracked

Comment: @Paolo Isn't committed.

Comment: @phd if it was tracked and the changes were not commited, `git` would not let you checkout the branch in the first place

Comment: @Paolo Partially true. Git allows to switch branches with some changes. If the changed file on the new branch is the same as in the old branch Git is not overwriting changes so it allows to switch branch with the modified file in the working tree.

Comment: @phd Fair enough